# Error Message using a custom class (Property type 'view' not found)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, custom-controls

I am using a custom class very similar to the Tweet Bot info panels in my application.  I have this class working perfectly when a button is tapped, however what I am trying to achieve is getting this 'alert panel' to show when my application finishes launching or comes from being idle.

To call this class using a standard I am using the following code;

```
-(IBAction) button1Tapped:(id) sender
{
    [MKInfoPanel showPanelInView:self.view 
                            type:MKInfoPanelTypeInfo 
                           title:@"Tweet Posted!" 
                        subtitle:nil 
                       hideAfter:2];
}
```

But I am having issues including this in my main AppDelegate.m.  I keep getting an error message of 'Property type view not found in Total_HealthAppDelegate when i use the following;

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

        [MKInfoPanel showPanelInView:self.view
                                type:MKInfoPanelTypeInfo 
                               title:@"Total:Health Support" 
                            subtitle:@"Welcome"
                           hideAfter:3];

}
```

Any advice would be great

Comment: I have found that whenever I reference like that, I have to use bracket syntax instead of dot. What happens when you try [self view] instead of self.view?

Comment: @HiGuy: `self.view` is equivalent to `[self view]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `self.window` in place of `self.view` when this code is inside the AppDelegate. Also be sure to include the appropriate header files and declare the class.

However, I recommend you put this code into the viewController that first wakes up instead. Here's one way to accomplish this.

Set up a `BOOL` in `NSUserDefaults` called `justWokeUp`. Then, in the appDelegate, set it to `YES` when the app wakes up:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [standardUserDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"justWokeUp];
}
```

Now, in any viewController that might be the first to load when the app resumes, check this value to see whether you should send the alert:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([standardUserDefaults boolForKey:@"justWokeUp"]) {

        [MKInfoPanel showPanelInView:self.view
                                type:MKInfoPanelTypeInfo 
                               title:@"Total:Health Support" 
                            subtitle:@"Welcome"
                           hideAfter:3];

        [standardUserDefaults setBool:NO forKey:@"justWokeUp"];


}
```

Comment: Hi, when i use self.window, it partially works but half of the info panel is displayed off the top of the iPhone screen

Comment: @iPhoneHelpr This is most likely due to the way you set up the frame in `MKInfoPanel`. Instead of putting this alert directly into the App Delegate, you may want to trigger the action in the first ViewController that comes onto the screen.

Comment: Yes, i have been experimenting with it, putting into the viewDidLoad method of my main view controller works and it displays fine.  However, If i then move to a new view, and then back it displays it again.  Only really want it displayed each time the app launches.

Comment: @iPhoneHelpr: See my edits above. This is just one of many ways to make sure that the display isn't triggered too ofte.

Comment: @PengOne - Thanks for the info.  When using NSUserDefaults in the appDelegate i get the following warning of 'NSUserDefaults may not respons to setBool:forKey' with the code you have included. Then the app crashes and Sigabrt

Comment: @iPhoneHelpr: It should read `setBool` not `setBOOL`. My fault; I corrected it above. This should now work.

Comment: @PengOne - Yes, thanks, that worked and did display the alert exactly as I wanted. However, upon exiting the app entirely then relaunching everything crashes.

Comment: Did you change `setBOOL` to `setBool` in the `viewWillAppear` method as well? Otherwise, sounds like a job for the debugger. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Yes, i changed everything to the correct code. If i leave your code how it is with setBool:YES then it doesnt show at all anymore either on launch of the app or when coming from idle.  However, if i change setBool:NO then it does show, but it shows everytime I go back to that main home screen.  The ideal behaviour would be to show once upon launch and not again, then everytime it comes out of multitasking if that makes sense

Comment: @iPhoneHelpr: Just saw another typo: `@"justWokeUp];` should read `@"justWokeUp"];`. That may be the problem. You may also want to sync the prefs: `[standardUserDefaults synchronize];` just in case.

Comment: @PengOne I had already corrected the missing speech mark issue :) It does work, but it doesn't exhibit the exact behaviour that I was looking for.